# Crashlytics CLS_Log vs. NSLog for production apps

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, debugging, crashlytics

No really a specific question, but I was curious if anyone has ever used [CLSLog() or CLSNSLog() provided by the Crashlytics SDK](http://www.crashlytics.com/blog/announcing-crashlytics-logs/)?

Up until now, my apps have been fairly small and I've just been leaving the NSLog's on all the time and even submitting the final app with them still in-tact.  In hindsight, I probably should turn these off, use some other logging system, or #define a DEBUG var that will disable them upon release as I've seen people discuss in other posts.

At any rate, just curious if anyone's used it before?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The best approach to this would be to declare a preprocessor variable called DEBUG

in the header, include:

`#define DEBUG 1`

After that, for debug purposes, set DEBUG to 1, and NSLog everything.

```
#if DEBUG==1
   NSLog(@"debug mode activated, value for certain variables is: %d", i);
#endif
```

Before you ship the product, just change

```
#define DEBUG 0
```

That way, you can just leave the entire code for debugging in the app, and keep it for further development

CLS_LOG from Crashlytics gives you access to the Log of the app from the Crashlytics website. It also gathers information about the crash, memory warnings, how many users crashed at a certain point, etc.

Happy coding!

edit:

I forgot to add one thing: for the application I'm working on right now, in the prefix, we defined:

```
#define NSLog(...) CLS_LOG(__VA_ARGS__)
```

So, we don't ever use CLS_LOG explicitly. We only use NSLog, but all the NSLogs make it to the Crashlytics dashboard.

Comment: Thanks for you comments / suggestions.

Comment: Where do I actually view the logs in the dashboard?

Comment: Go to your dashboard, click one of the crashes, and just below the graphs, you should see "Viewing latest crash (More details...)". Just click on the "More details..." link to view the Log for the latest crash.

Comment: you don't have to manually change the env settings. Check "Preprocessor Macros" in build settings

Answer (score 1):

I created some `.h` file with all the common constants that I need to use and added it `.pch` file (in order not to make mess in it).I also imported `CrashLytics` via pods (some why `.pch` didn't recognised it if I included in project the usual way)

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#define NSLog(...) CLS_LOG(__VA_ARGS__)
#define ServerURL    @"http://TestServer"
#else
#define ServerURL    @"http://RealServer" 
#define NSLog(...)
```

Comment: Isn't that the wrong way around and you should have CLS_LOG after the second NSLog ? and something like printf after the first one ?

Comment: Jules, not sure if I understood your question. My code is merely an example (in debug mode while testing I wasn't concerned about performance so I could forward it to crashlytics in the release mode to make it as faster for the user I prefer to used Nslog , in the end I commented even the Nslog). For the first release I think I still used to have the CLS_Log until I was sure I got a stable app. In the end its up to u , hope I helped.

Comment: Ok, I think I got what you mean . I did the NSLog first in order to always use it no matter if I am in debug or release (I think its more convenient)

Comment: didn't you notice any performance lag in recording all NSLog with CLS_LOG? since it is recording to crashlytics server. I have noticed the performance issue with my app. It seems they are recording on main thread. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I think its up to you on which thread to execute NSLog or CLS_LOG ( I really doubt if they start the main thread especially for that). In any case NSLog by itself is pretty expensive (u can always use Time Profiler to check it. From my observation it was around 8%).Crashlytics save the logs on the disk, after the app is crashed he will send the report when u launch the app for second time.Hope I helped.

Comment: Just noticed this old thread I think Srinivas G you were right use main thread. sorry for confusion.